# How/where would you add a custom INSERT MySQL query to different table for when a new post is published in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, insert, publish

I'm trying to place a record of a newly published post in a separate db table aside from the regular process a post goes through to get published.

I've tried going into `post.php` in my `wp-includes` folder, and adding a query inside `function wp_insert_post()` but this adds records for `Auto Drafts` and each time an update is made.

I've also tried including my insert statement in the `function wp_publish_post()` function of this same file. This doesn't do anything.

Is there a specific part in either of these functions or maybe a different file entirely that I should be placing my `INSERT` statement into to add a record each time a new post is published?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hook_to_WordPress

Comment: As Marc B pointed, you should try with hooks, it is the optimal solution for what are you trying to achieve. Create a custom plugin and use the hooks you need.

Comment: if you want to insert or update anything while your post insert or update then there is not need to make changes in your base file instead use wordpress hooks. I think that forum link would help you https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to your `post.php` file located in the `wp-includes` folder.

Find the `wp_insert_post()` function and use this code right before the `return` statement as your SQL query.

```
if ($postarr['post_status'] == 'publish') {

    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=YOURDBNAME;host=YOURHOST;charset=utf8',
                        'YOURUSERNAME',
                        'YOURPASSWORD');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "did not connect...";
    }

    $sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (?, ?, 0)");
    $sth->execute(array($value1, $value2));

}
```